# Beginner question: How to divide (split up) two or several independant areas (for 2D usage) in openGL/openTK

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, split, opentk

**Hi, i struggle to learn openGL,** so i'm programming a simple old-school 2D game with **c#/.net/openTK**. So far, i can recommend that combination; it's easy to use and works quite well.

I've successfully managed to code a smooth and performant x/y 2D scrolling with spare room for a "headline", using:

```
protected override void OnRenderFrame (FrameEventArgs e)
{
  ...
  GL.MatrixMode (MatrixMode.Projection);

  GL.LoadIdentity ();
  GL.Ortho (-ClientSize.Width                                       / 2f,   ClientSize.Width                                       / 2f, 
            (ClientSize.Height + GRP.GAME_HEADLINE_SIZE_PIX.Height) / 2f, (-ClientSize.Height + GRP.GAME_HEADLINE_SIZE_PIX.Height) / 2f, 
            0, 1);
  ...
}

private void CGame_Resize (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  GL.Viewport (0, -GRP.GAME_HEADLINE_SIZE_PIX.Height, gw.ClientSize.Width - 0, gw.ClientSize.Height);
}
```

**So now i want to populate this empty headline area with some GPU-worthy headline content,** 
but i'm just too inexperienced to know how to have openTk handle it. And stuck.

---

Google and stackoverflow yielded these vague clues so far:

- Use a 2nd framebuffer.
- Use "Viewport" and/or "Scissors".
- Use "CreateContext" and "MakeCurrent", like sugested here:
  [How to use multiple viewports in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726379/how-to-use-multiple-viewports-in-opengl/31012256#31012256)

In the end, I might have to get this example to run, but alas, all the code download links are broken there:
http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/multiple_viewports/20002/

---

**So, can anyone tell me what's best practice for handling two indendent 2D areas using openTK? - Any hint or code snippet would be highly appreciated!**

Best regards,
Al

*PS: this is my very 1st community post ever, so thanks for bearing with me!*

Comment: FYI [here is a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072696/380384) that shows how to render text into a texture and show it on a 3D face.